# Why doesn't `spdiags` put a vector in the correct place?

Tags: matlab, vector, diagonal

I have a vector that has `1`'s in some places, and I want to create a diagonal using the vector.  The vector is called `one_vec_two`:

```
n = 4;

one_vec_two = zeros(n*n, 1);
one_vec_two(1,1) = 1;
for k=0:(n-1)
    one_vec_two(k*n+1, 1) = 1;
end

non_zero_vecs = [one_vec_two];
placement = [n-1];

A = spdiags(non_zero_vecs, placement, n*n, n*n);
fullA = full(A);
disp(A)
```

The first element of the vector `one_vec_two` is a 1:

```
>> one_vec_two(1)

ans =

     1
```

And, I placed the vector starting at diagonal `n-1`, which is `3`.  But, when I go to column 4, I don't see it:

```
>> fullA(1,4)

ans =

     0
```

Why isn't MATLAB putting my vector in the correct spot?

Answer (score 1):

As per the doc for `spdiag`,

`Note   In this syntax, if a column of B is longer than the diagonal it is replacing, and m >= n, spdiags takes elements of super-diagonals from the lower part of the column of B, and elements of sub-diagonals from the upper part of the column of B.`

it is placing the **lower** part of your vector into the location specified.  Hence the result is as expected.

It looks like you want something like

```
A = spdiags(non_zero_vecs([end-placement+1:end 1:end-placement]), placement, n*n, n*n)
```

or

```
A = spdiags(non_zero_vecs, -placement, n*n, n*n)'
```

which both do the same thing, just in slightly different ways.